# How to force Nextjs to read head tags

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-headers

I have head tags in both my _app.tsx and my _document.tsx pages in my nextjs app (with react v18).

I can't make the browswer tab update with the title or favicon that are saved in those Head tags.

In app.tsx I have:

```
<>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"></link>
      </Head>
    
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</ApolloProvider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </>
```

In _document.tsx I have:

```
  <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta name="theme-color" key="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <meta name="description" content="this is my description" key="description" />
          <meta property="og:title" content="i expect to see this in the browser tab" key="title" />
          <meta property="og:description" content="can't get these tags to populate" key="og:description" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"  />
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&family=Kristi&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>
```

What can I do to force nextjs to read my head tags?

I have tried adding all of these to the _document.tsx file:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/public/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

I have files named as each of these saved in a public folder.

Comment: What title do you see in the browser's tab?  Have you tried removing the meta tags from `_document` and move them to `_app` instead?

Comment: I see local host 3000/[followed by the page path ]

Comment: If I add a head tag to a layout component, I can make the title appear in the browser tab, but that doesn't help with the favicon and I dont want to have to do that on every layout - I just want he same favicon and title on every page

Comment: Try also adding `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />` in addition to the other favicon links (make sure `favicon.ico` exists in your `public` folder).

Comment: The difference between your suggestion and what I have been trying is the inclusion of the word 'shortcut' in the 'rel' attribute. I tried adding that word, but still get the same problem - the details don't populate in the browser tab

Answer (score 0):

With next/head, you can put your head tags inside a page in which you write a functional component like that

```
import React from "react";
import Head from 'next/head';

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Why us</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo192.png" />
      </Head>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyPage;
```

**UPDATE FOR GENERIC SOLUTION**

Head component

```
import React from 'react';
import NextHead from 'next/head';

const Head = ({ title, description }) => (
  <NextHead>
    <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
    <title>{title || ''}</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />  {/* icon image */}
    <meta name="description" content={description || ''} />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  </NextHead>
);

export default Head;
```

We use Head component inside layout.tsx

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return(
    <>
      <Head title="Generic Title" description="Generic Title" />
      <div id="layout-wrapper">
        <Header /> {/*your header component*/}
        <main>
          <Sidebar /> {/*your sidebar component*/}
          <div className="main-content">{children}</div>
        </main>
        <Footer /> {/*your footer component*/}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now we use Layout component inside _app.js

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  )

}
```

**UPDATE FOR PAGE SPECIFIC TITLE APPROACH**

_app.js

```
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

  return(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <div className="page-content">
          <NextSeo
            defaultTitle="Generic Title"
            title={pageProps && pageProps.title ? pageProps.title : ""}
          />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  )

}
```

Example page

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

const Example = () => {
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  return {
    props: {
      title: 'Example Page'
    },
  };
};
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

You can also use Head tags for your app like below

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My Next App</title>
        <meta name='description' content='This is a desription for My Next App'/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmet  are you saying that my error is importing Head instead of NextHead from next/head? Are you saying that nextjs wont use head tags if they are contained in the app.tsx and document.tsx files? I can't  see how the favicon can work from layout files. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Do you import Head from 'next/document/ inside _document.tsx ?

Comment: No - the import statement is in app.tsx. _document.tsx has an import statement for Head from next/document

Comment: Either way, I tried your generic suggestion - the google fonts have to be in the _document head statement, but even still, I can't get the rest of it to work from inside a separate NextHead component. Do you know of any documentation or tutorials that explain how to force the head tags to be applied in a next js app?

Comment: I have updated my answer for last time, maybe it works now

Comment: I've tried adding the tags to app.tsx - but they also don't populate the browser tab. Thanks anyway for trying to suggest something